# Es posible que haya una forma mejor (óptima) de escribir esta QUERY?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo esta consulta donde traigo cosas de 3 tablas diferentes, y utilizo los if o ifnull para buscar otra cosa, el problema es que cuando tengo que agregar un filtro por detalle de artículo tengo que realizar en el where de nuevo un select y hace que la consulta sea muy lenta,

Me interesaría saber si exite otra forma de optimizar esta consulta para que no sea tan lenta

```
SELECT
    IF(
        b.detalle = '',
        (
        SELECT
            detalle
        FROM
            inventario
        WHERE
            codigo = b.codigo AND idEmpresa = b.idEmpresa
    ),
    b.detalle
    ) AS detalle,
    b.codigo,
    b.precio,
    IFNULL(
        (
        SELECT
            Costo
        FROM
            inventario
        WHERE
            codigo = b.codigo AND idEmpresa = b.idEmpresa
    ),
    0
    ) AS costo,
    b.cantidad,
    a.*
FROM
    comprobantes a,
    articulos b
WHERE
    a.id = b.comprobante AND a.idEmpresa = 12 AND a.fecha >= '2022-05-01' AND a.fecha <= '2022-06-01' AND IF(
        b.detalle = '',
        (
        SELECT
            detalle
        FROM
            inventario
        WHERE
            codigo = b.codigo AND idEmpresa = b.idEmpresa
    ),
    b.detalle
    ) LIKE '%sup%'
ORDER BY
    a.id
DESC
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! necesitamos saber la cantidad de datos, y el explain plan de esta consulta.. tambien los indices de cada tabla...

Comment: Te vas a ahorrar mucho si haces `JOIN inventario`.